# Sinon: Test React component method is calling function pass as a prop (Mocha + Chai + Sinon is being used for unit test)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, chai, react-test-renderer

I have a react component which has a method

```
export class Hit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.triggerClick= this.triggerClick.bind(this);
    }

triggerClick(event) {
    this.props.triggerClick(event.target.click);
}

render() {
    return (
....................................
                        <input ........ onChange={this.triggerClick} />
.............................................
           );
    }
}
```

I want to check if triggerClick(event) method is being called or not. Hence, I am pasting the code I have related to this. Though if you see in the logs of the hitComponent something like below,

**onChange: [Function: bound triggerClick]**

log of spy says it is not being called. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
let mockFunction = sinon.fake();

let hitComponent = renderShallow(<Hit ........ triggerClick= {mockFunction}/>)

let spy = sinon.spy(Hit.prototype, 'triggerClick');

console.log(hitComponent)
console.log(spy)
```

o/p:
hitComponent:

```
[ { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: 'input',
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    props:
     { type: '.....',
       checked: true,
       onChange: [Function: bound triggerClick] },
.....}]
```

o/p:
spy:

```
{ [Function: proxy]
  isSinonProxy: true,
  called: false,
  notCalled: true,
  calledOnce: false,
  calledTwice: false,
  calledThrice: false,
  callCount: 0,
  firstCall: null,
  secondCall: null,
  thirdCall: null,
  lastCall: null,
  args: [],
  returnValues: [],
  thisValues: [],
  exceptions: [],
  callIds: [],
  errorsWithCallStack: [],
  displayName: 'triggerClick',
  toString: [Function: toString],
  instantiateFake: [Function: create],
  id: 'spy#1',
  stackTraceError:
   Error: Stack Trace for original
       at wrapMethod ..........

 restore: { [Function] sinon: true },
  wrappedMethod: [Function: triggerClick]
}
```

There is a helper class to use react-test-renderer

```
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';


function renderShallow(component) {
    const shallowRenderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(component);
    return  shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();;
}

export {renderShallow}
```

Answer (score 0):

`triggerClick` is bound when a class is instantiated. It cannot be spied or mocked on `Hit.prototype` after that.

It should be either:

```
let spy = sinon.spy(Hit.prototype, 'triggerClick');
let hitComponent = renderShallow(<Hit triggerClick= {mockFunction}/>)
```

Or:

```
let hitComponent = renderShallow(<Hit triggerClick= {mockFunction}/>)
sinon.spy(hitComponent.instance(), 'triggerClick');
```

Comment: Both seems to be not working. 1st option is having no change. 2nd option is throwing "TypeError: hitComponent.instance
is not a function"

Comment: I expect the first option to work, this is how a method should be spied. Since the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve but just several snippets, I'm unable to tell why it doesn't work. `onChange` event isn't triggered in the code you posted, for starters. If it isn't triggered really, that's the reason for `triggerClick` to not be called.

Comment: It's also unclear what `renderShallow` is. I assumed that this is Enzyme's `shallow`, and in this case there would be such function, https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html . In case Enzyme isn't used, consider updating the question with relevant info.

Comment: Sorry I missed to add the code for renderShallow which I did now. It is a helper component to use shallow stuff from the react. Also, if you see the output of hitComponent, it shows the below for onchange,  onChange: [Function: bound triggerClick] } which I thought is triggering the method.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that suggests that you trigger onchange event or call triggerClick in any other way. So it's not called and there's nothing to spy on. I don't use react-test-renderer myself and cannot suggest a good way to trigger an event with it, but it's possibly `hitComponent.props.onChange()` and then assert that a spy was called. Notice that even the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html suggests to use Enzyme's shallow renderer because react-test-renderer is lacking. I'd suggest to do this.

Comment: Yes, I didn't had the simulator which would trigger the onchange event. Thanks you for pointing me in the right direction. Sorry, for replying late.